# Continuous serialization of complex object collection to file

Tags: .net, xml-serialization

I'm working on an application that record the state of a compplex system.
I've to record these states to xml files (using xml serialisation).
This file is used to replay the recorded event and analyse it.

the context:

My application display a set of complex data (we called this a VIEW)
each view contains 1 object and 2 collections of objects (400 items each with about 20 properties).

The application record a state of the data at fixed interval (the time between 2 record may vary from 5 sec to 60 min), all records are stored in a VIEWS collection and we save this collection of VIEW to a trace file (using xmlserializer and serialise my object collection to a text writer)

All works well but when the file reach about 20 Mo, the file save can take more time than the time between 2 record event (file are stored on the network and sometime we have lags) and we wants to optimize this.

So my question is :

**Is there a way to append an object to a file without have to load and write the entire file or a way to optimize the serialisation to file?**

We have to use xml serialisation because the file must be readable by human & by code (deserialisation).

Comment: Do you need to have the serialized objects available to the file immediately (or in semi-realtime) ?  If not, you could perhaps offload the serialisation and file I/O to a message queue for parallel/ asynchronous processing?

Comment: Yes, the serialized object should be immediatly available (in case on system shutdown, the last know state must be available in the trace file)

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean it needs to be robust enough to recover/degrade gracefully with no loss of data or if the serialised objects need to be available for some other core functionality as the system is running. If you only need to ensure that data is not lost in the event of a catastrophic system event e.g. someone accidentally shuts the system down, I would be inclined to look into using queuing. Your active system would then only need to dump the state to MSMQ or similar and the serialiser code, running on a different box, could do the resource-hungry I/O operations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a database? Those things are made to solve problems like these :) If you want to do it manually, you will have to declare your own protocol. A primitive working implementation:

```
[Serializable]
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private static string Serialize(Test instance)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, instance);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());
    }
}
private static Test Deserialize(string instance)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Test));
    byte[] instanceBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(instance);

    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(instanceBytes))
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(stream) as Test;
    }
}



public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // write some test objects
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.WriteLine(Serialize(new Test() { Name = "test1" }));
        writer.WriteLine(Serialize(new Test() { Name = "test2" }));
        writer.WriteLine(Serialize(new Test() { Name = "test3" }));
        writer.Flush();

        // reset
        stream.Position = 0;

        // read them back again
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        Test test1 = Deserialize(reader.ReadLine());
        Test test2 = Deserialize(reader.ReadLine());
        Test test3 = Deserialize(reader.ReadLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Will investigate this. but we can't used database, file should be readable with xml/text editors (notepad, xmlspy, ....)

Comment: in that case you should create custom serialization/deserialization logic (recommend to use xlinq here)